# Applying Blahut-Arimoto Algorithm for AWGN Channels Capacity Calculation with Cost

Tags: digital-communications, continuous-signals, information-theory, capacity

I am exploring the Blahut-Arimoto algorithm (or any numerical method) for channel capacity calculations, particularly for continuous channels. I understand its application in discrete scenarios, but I am unsure about its adaptation to continuous channels such as AWGN channels. Could someone provide insights or a step-by-step guide on how to apply the Blahut-Arimoto algorithm for AWGN channel capacity calculations with power cost? Additionally, are there any specific considerations or modifications needed for the algorithm in the continuous case?

Your expertise and guidance would be greatly appreciated!